# Using a TreeItem with a Widget as content in a single GWT UiBinder template

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am attempting to initialise a `TreeItem` with a `Widget` defined within a UI Binder template as the `TreeItem`'s content. Initially I started with a template like this:

```
<g:Tree>
    <g:TreeItem>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <p>This is the root item's content.</p>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:TreeItem>
            <g:HTMLPanel>
                <p>This is the child's content.</p>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:TreeItem>
    </g:TreeItem>
</g:Tree>
```

Expecting to end up with a tree structure something like this:

```
+ This is the root item's content.
```

Expanding to:

```
- This is the root item's content.
 \ This is the child's content.
```

But this doesn't work. The `HTMLPanel` widgets are created as children of the `TreeItem`s, rather than being the items' widgets, so I end up with a structure like this:

```
- (root item has no content)
 \ This is the root item's content.
  - (first child has no content)
   \ This is the child's content.
```

So I tried extending the `TreeItem` class like so:

```
public class WidgetTreeItem extends TreeItem {

    @UiChild(tagname="widget", limit=1)
    public void setWidget(IsWidget isWidget) {
        super.setWidget(isWidget.asWidget());
    }

}
```

And then, importing the package containing `WidgetTreeItem` into the `c` namespace, I have a template like this:

```
<g:Tree>
    <c:WidgetTreeItem>
        <c:widget>
            <g:HTMLPanel>
                <p>This is the root item's content.</p>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </c:widget>
        <!-- Should create a child TreeItem with the HTMLPanel as its Widget. -->
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <p>This is the child's content.</p>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </c:WidgetTreeItem>
</g:Tree>
```

But this doesn't work, either. It fails with the following exception:

`Only TreeItem or Widget subclasses are valid children: <c:WidgetTreeItem>`.

Can anyone see how to achieve what I am attempting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a little inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2830777/1509381), I have found my solution. Given my original example, the XML now looks like this:

```
<g:Tree>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="rootContent">
        <p>This is the root item's content.</p>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="childContent">
        <p>This is the child's content.</p>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:TreeItem widget="{rootContent}">
        <g:TreeItem widget="{childContent}">
        </g:TreeItem>
    </g:TreeItem>
</g:Tree>
```

Some playing around was required here. Most notably, this only works provided that the content panels are contained within a widget implementing the `HasWidgets` interface. The `Tree` class satisfies this requirement. It is also worth noting that the content fields must be defined *before* they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Probably following could help you.

```
<g:Tree>
    <g:TreeItem text="This is the first parent item's content.">
        <g:TreeItem text="This is the child 1's content." />
        <g:TreeItem text="This is the child 2's content." />

    </g:TreeItem>

    <g:TreeItem text="This is the second parent item's content.">
        <g:TreeItem text="This is the child 3's content." />
        <g:TreeItem text="This is the child 4's content." />

    </g:TreeItem>
</g:Tree>
```

You can append TreeItems as many as you want.

Comment: This would have been my approach, the problem being that the content, in reality, is to contain complex widgets, not just text. Essentially I was looking for a way to use the `TreeItem(Widget w)` constructor. The self-answer I provided achieved exactly the desired results, once I figured out how to structure the template.